# WIX.com Schema JSON-LD Snippets Problems

Tags: json, metadata, google-rich-snippets

**WIX.com Schema Snippets Problems**

I'm trying to install some schema snippets into my Wix website and I keep getting errors.

Somebody said

> Your code has 4  tags in it, and you're using different Schema
>   types

Wix help says:

> You can use one main JSON-LD, nesting is allowed.

I removed the script tags but I'm not sure how to "nest" the different Schema types. Any help would be greatly appreciated

-Jeff

**The code is here:** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QWAkjjExws7IdYH25HuBbGN5gkeSDlusXlYdS56vO0Q/edit?usp=sharing

**Here are the WIX JSON Guidelines:**

- If you get an error, check your structured data and make sure:
- Your code is in the JSON-LD format.
- Your code begins with the HTML tag  and ends with .
- Within the tag, the JSON-LD itself is wrapped in curly brackets { } .
- Each element in the JSON-LD is separated from the next one with a comma. However, the last element shouldn't have a comma after it.
- Your code is using straight quotes "". Curly quotes “” don't pass validation.
- Your code is using only one script tag, and this script tag includes only one main schema markup type (one main JSON-LD, nesting is allowed).
- All fields have the format: "key":"content". Pressing 'Enter' in either field won't pass validation, for example:
- Pass validation: "text" : "this is a sentence with text."
- FAIL validation: "text" : "this is a
  sentence with text."
- Your code contains less than 7,000 characters. Code with over 7,000 characters can not be added.

Answer (score 0):

You have added multiple top level entities which is not a valid syntax. To get around it you need to define a top level entity that contains all the others. This is done by using @graph and listing the others in an array. e.g.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@graph": [
    {
        
        "@type": "TravelAgency",
        "name": "ColombiaMotoAdventures",
        "image": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/331b1d_452c7e9b5e304d2ca37e16dc81141be6~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_270,h_270,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/331b1d_452c7e9b5e304d2ca37e16dc81141be6~mv2.png",
        "@id": "",
        "url": "https://www.ColombiaMotoAdventures",
        "telephone": "3214917060",
        "priceRange": "80-100",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "Cra. 102, Loma de Pajarito ##68-36",
            "addressLocality": "Medellin",
            "postalCode": "",
            "addressCountry": "CO"
        },
        "openingHoursSpecification": {
            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek": [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
                "Sunday"
            ],
            "opens": "09:00",
            "closes": "18:00"
        },
        "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/ColombiaMotoAdventures"
    },
{
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "Colombia Moto Adventures",
  "url": "https://www.colombiamotoadventures.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://www.colombiamotoadventures.com/?s={search_term_string}{search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
},
{
    "@type": "Trip",
    "name": "Colombia Motorcycle Tour",
    "description": "The dozen best places and areas that should be on your list when visiting Medellin, Colombia. Our motorcycle tours and rentals are geared towards beginner and intermediate riders. We have lots of people come down and tour around who don't speak a word of Spanish and they do just fine. Our tours are also geared towards beginner and intermediate riders. We are an American owned ADV motorcycle rental company based in Medellin, Colombia. Our motorcycles are perfect for comfortable, long-distance touring but are also capable to take you mud, rocks and river-crossings if that's where you decide to go.",
    "itinerary": [
        {
            "@type": "Country",
            "name": "Colombia",
            "description": "Colombia is projected as one of Latin America's main destinations in terms of adventure tourism, multiple cultural activities, the best gastronomy, so that you can make your tourism trip an unforgettable experience. It is a country that makes you vibrate with its emotions, where you can choose the destination of your preference.",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombia"
        }
    ]
},
{
  "@type": "TouristTrip",
  "name": "Colombia",
  "description": "This trip is modeled as several distinct Tourist Trips using the subTrip property.",
  "subTrip": [
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Colombia Jungle Motorcycle Adventure",
        "description": "Rent a motorcycle in Medellin and drive to the jungle. Swim in the crystal clear waters of a jungle river and drink cold beers while listening to the amazing sounds of the jungle at night. The perfect South America motorcycle route"
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Guatape Motorcycle Trip",
        "description": "Ride a motorcycle to Guatape and have lunch! Leave Medellín in the morning and take a drive out to the town of Guatape."
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Suzuki DR650 Motorcycle Rental",
        "description": "Rent a DR650 motorcycle in Colombia. Known as the worlds best dual-sport motorcycle take your South America motorcycle adventure with this!  "
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Medellin Motorcycle Trout Fishing Day Trip",
        "description": "Ride an adventure motorcycle into the remote backcountry outside of Medellin and catch trout with a local family. "
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Cerro del Padre Amaya Off-Road Motorcycle Trip",
        "description": "Boquerón to Padre Amaya - This is where things get interesting, We take our motorcycles and start heading up an off-road trail stunning views and high altitude."
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Colombia Waterfalls Motobike Tour",
        "description": "Want to explore beyond Guatape? This motorcycle trip is for you! San Carlos is a small pueblo near Medellín that hasn’t yet been discovered by many foreigners. But it’s a hidden gem surrounded by mountains, rivers, waterfalls, and nature."
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Medellin Motorcycle Rental",
        "description": "Motorcycle Tours and Rentals in Medellin, Colombia. We have the best selection of adventure motorcycles in Colombia Suzuki DR650, Honda XRE300, Kawasaki Versys-X 300."
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "5 Day Colombia Lost Emerald City Motorcycle Tour",
        "description": "Off-Road Colombia - Journey to the Lost Emerald City. Ride motorcycles off-road through rugged terrain, cross mountain ranges, and streams see amazing vistas and waterfalls and finally get the chance to and interact with local emerald miners. You can even buy emeralds directly from the miners in the field!"
      },
      {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "Colombia Coffee Region Motorcycle Tour",
        "description": "Take an amazing motorcycle trip through Colombia's Coffee Region. Swim in the hot springs in Santa Rosa and take a coffee tour in Salento as well as walking through the Wax Palms in the Valle Cocora, and as always, enjoy all the twists and turns while riding through some of the amazing scenery in the world."
      },
          {
        "@type": "TouristTrip",
        "name": "19 Day Colombia to Ecuador Motorcycle Trip",
        "description": "Journey To The Center Of The Earth. Based on customer feedback, we have decided to turn our most popular South America motorcycle route in Colombia into a full motorcycle tour through the most beautiful parts of Colombia and Ecuador. Rent a motorcycle in Medellin, Colombia, and ride to Quito, Ecuador and back."
      }
    ]
}]
}
</script>
```